# Runtime library importing in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, import, runtime

I would like to know how I can import a library into Objective-C at runtime. I'm new to Objective-C and this may be a complex question, but I'm fairly proficient in C/C++,

I'm developing a modular application where specific modules (libraries) are loaded as needed. Basically I have a name in runtime, like "nodeX", and I want to load a library that has it.

I've been searching for a way to do this but have been unsuccessful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [NSBundle](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Note that you can't safely unload code on Mac OS X, Objective-C or otherwise, unless you are so terribly careful that it just isn't worth the effort to do so.

Note, also, that you can't dynamically load code on iOS.